# Is there any way to convert a float to a character array?

Tags: java, android, types, casting, type-conversion

Here is what i would like to do . I have floating point number, for example `456.345`, I want to convert it to a character array such that I get .

```
chArry = {'4','5','6','.','3','4','5'}.
```

Comment: Do you know how to convert a `float` to a `String`?

Comment: Simply convert your float value to String then you easily access char from string at specific index or as char[].

Comment: You *may* want to specify/limit the number of decimal precision.. otherwise there could be some odd edge cases, depending where the value comes from.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just convert it to string first, then to a character array.

```
String.valueOf(someFloat).toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
float f = 456.345f;
char[] chArry = ("" + f).toCharArray();
System.out.print("" + chArry[2]);
```